# aside won't float next to article

Tags: html, css, css-float

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzKRy.png) shows my problem. There is a perfect space for the `aside` element to fit next to the article. I want to put it there, but I don't want to use a relative position, I would just like to use the `float` tag.

My understanding is, that everything should be an `inline-block` to float, for example: An `aside` tag next to an `article` tag, but I'm stuck here.

(Also the commentary `/*position:relative .... */` would let the `aside` tag show next to the `article`, but this is not the right way for my task.)

CSS:

```
article {
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* overflow: scroll; */
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #94bae7 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#94bae7), to(#fff));
    display: inline-block;
}
#article-container {
    display:inline-block;
}
.rondehoeken {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    /* position: relative;
    top: -410px;
    left: 230px; */ 
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section id="content">
    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Antwerpen Marathon</h1>
        </hgroup>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="inschrijven.html">Inschrijven</a></li>
                <li><a href="nieuwsbrief.html">Nieuwsbrief</a></li>
                <li><a href="resultaten.html">Resultaten</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <div id="intro">
            <div id="rodelogo" class="logo">
            <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
            <div id="blauwelogo" class="logo">
            <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
            <div id="groenelogo" class="logo">
            <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <article class="rondehoeken">
    <header>
        <div class="streep1"></div>
        <div class="streep2"></div>
        <div class="streep3"></div>
        <div class="streep4"></div>
        <div class="streep5"></div>
        <h1>Titeltje dabei</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="artikel-container">
    <p id="item">
    Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>. Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te 
    geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een 
    <em>voorbeeldtekst</em>. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, 
    die nu nog niet bekend <abbr title="Islamitische Staat">IS</abbr>. De <strong>faketekst</strong> is dus een tekst die eigenlijk 
    nergens over gaat. Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. 
    Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door. <br />
    Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>. Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te 
    geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een 
    voorbeeldtekst. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, 
    die nu nog niet bekend is. De <mark>faketekst</mark> is dus een tekst die eigenlijk 
    nergens over gaat. Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. 
    Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door.
    Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>.
    </p>
    </div>
    <aside>
        <div id="video-container">
            <video controls width="150" height="250" preload id="videos" poster="images/download.png">
            <source src="images/dunk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div id="advert1" class="rondehoeken">
            <a href="#"> <br /> <br />Recyclen!<br /> <br /></a>
        </div>
        <div id="advert2" class="rondehoeken">
            <a href="#"><img id="snickers" src="images/bar.png" width="150px" alt="muzieklogo"></a>
        </div>
    <footer>
        <ul class="galerij">
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish1.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish2.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish3.jpg"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish4.jpg"></a></li>
        </ul>
        <br /><br /><br /><br />
        <small>&copy; Marathon van Antwerpen</small>
    </footer>
    </aside>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: your article has a fixed width, and you are placing the `aside` within that fixed width. so it would never expand out that width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is maybe not exactly what you are looking for but just to show you that
your article has a fixed width, and you are placing the `aside` within that fixed width. so it would never expand out that width. Place it outside and it would go to the right.

Also i added an `div` tag around the article and aside tags for styling purposes on the codepen link.

Here is an codepen how it would look : [Click ME](https://codepen.io/Ylama/pen/wpOeYr)

```css
article {
    float: left;
    width: 540px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    /* overflow: scroll; */
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
    border: solid 1px #ddd;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #94bae7 0%, #fff 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#94bae7), to(#fff));
    display: inline-block;
}
#article-container {
    display:inline-block;
}
.rondehoeken {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}
aside {
    /* position: relative;
    top: -410px;
    left: 230px; */ 
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<section id="content">
        <header>
            <hgroup>
                <h1>Antwerpen Marathon</h1>
            </hgroup>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#top">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="inschrijven.html">Inschrijven</a></li>
                    <li><a href="nieuwsbrief.html">Nieuwsbrief</a></li>
                    <li><a href="resultaten.html">Resultaten</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <div id="intro">
                <div id="rodelogo" class="logo">
                <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
                <div id="blauwelogo" class="logo">
                <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
                <div id="groenelogo" class="logo">
                <span id="iam">I An</span>twerpen</div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <article class="rondehoeken">
        <header>
            <div class="streep1"></div>
            <div class="streep2"></div>
            <div class="streep3"></div>
            <div class="streep4"></div>
            <div class="streep5"></div>
            <h1>Titeltje dabei</h1>
        </header>
        <div id="artikel-container">
        <p id="item">
        Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>. Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te 
        geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een 
        <em>voorbeeldtekst</em>. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, 
        die nu nog niet bekend <abbr title="Islamitische Staat">IS</abbr>. De <strong>faketekst</strong> is dus een tekst die eigenlijk 
        nergens over gaat. Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. 
        Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door. <br />
        Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>. Alles wat hier staat is slechts om een indruk te 
        geven van het grafische effect van tekst op deze plek. Wat u hier leest is een 
        voorbeeldtekst. Deze wordt later vervangen door de uiteindelijke tekst, 
        die nu nog niet bekend is. De <mark>faketekst</mark> is dus een tekst die eigenlijk 
        nergens over gaat. Het grappige is, dat mensen deze toch vaak lezen. 
        Zelfs als men weet dat het om een faketekst gaat, lezen ze toch door.
        Dit is een <i>faketekst</i>.
        </p>
        </div>
        
        </article>
  <aside>
            <div id="video-container">
                <video controls width="150" height="250" preload id="videos" poster="images/download.png">
                <source src="images/dunk.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
            </div>
            <div id="advert1" class="rondehoeken">
                <a href="#"> <br /> <br />Recyclen!<br /> <br /></a>
            </div>
            <div id="advert2" class="rondehoeken">
                <a href="#"><img id="snickers" src="images/bar.png" width="150px" alt="muzieklogo"></a>
            </div>
        <footer>
            <ul class="galerij">
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish1.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish2.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish3.jpg"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/finish4.jpg"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <br /><br /><br /><br />
            <small>&copy; Marathon van Antwerpen</small>
        </footer>
        </aside>
    </section>
```

Comment: Omg you can't believe how happy I am hahaha! Thanks a lot, the problem was indeed the fixed-width, I just used a percentage-width in the article tag and it worked as planned! THANK YOU @Ylama!!!